# Replace characters in a string in LC-3

Tags: lc3

So I have this 80 bit number:

```
gen1    .stringz          "01000100010000010100110001000101010011011101111010100110100100100001110100110011"
```

I have to replace the (0's with 1's) and (1's with 0's). I'm really confused at how i would go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach would be as follows:

- Load the address of the string (it's not really a number) (hint: LEA)
- Keep a counter so you know when you've seen all 80 (hint: LD)
- Look at the memory address you loaded (hint: LDR)
- Overwrite the memory address with the new value (hint: STR)
- Increment your counter
- Repeat until the counter hits 80